# what's the mechanism of str.endswith(suffix[, start, end])?

Tags: python

I'm super confused about how `start` and `end` work. I supposed this function starts to count at `start`th element then ends at `end`th element after `start`th element. I mean, for example, if I define `start` and `end` as 1 and 2, the element should be looked at 3. I was wrong:

```
a = "orange"
a.endswith("g", 0, 5)
```

returns `True`;

```
a = "orange"
a.endswith("g", 1, 5)
```

also returns `True`. Any explanation is appreciate!

Comment: `a.endswith("g", 1, 5)` is true because `a[1:5]` -> "rang" ends with `g`. Slices don't include the last index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0):

> > I mean, for example, if I define  start and end as 1 and 2, the element should be looked at 3.

The `start` parameter represents how many characters must be skipped from the start of the string. Ok so far.
The `end` parameter **does not represent the length** from the start character, but the index of the ending character (excluded) in the source string, pretty much like slicing, as pointed out by Mark Meyer.